# DolphinDB: data of 2038.01.20 cannot be filtered out based on the DATETIME type

Tags: dolphindb

When querying data in DolphinDB, the data of 2038.01.20 cannot be filtered out based on the DATETIME type. 2038.01.19 can be filtered.

Answer (score 0):

The data type overflows. The DATETIME type is represented by a 4-bit integer, and the maximum is 2038.01.19. Using a TIMESTAMP type to avoid such problems.